# MySQL Error: Can't create/write to file Errcode: 17

Tags: mysql, pentaho-spoon

We are working on a data migration project in which the source and target databases are MySql (Version : 5.0.45-community-nt).

Currently both the source and target databases are hosted on my local machine (Windows XP SP2).

We are using a tool called “Pentaho spoon” for writing the ETL scripts for migration. The spoon transformation fetches and loads data into the target database.

The transformation is a set of select and insert steps.

Problem :

Execution of the script throws following error for the select statements in the transformation:

`Can't create/write to file 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\Data\#sql_29c_0.MYI' (Errcode: 17)`

ErrCode 17 refers to: OS error code  17:  File exists

It is noticed that some random temporary files named in the format `#sql_29c_0.MYI`,  `#sql_29c_0.MYD` are created in the directory: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\Data` at runtime and these files are deleted in process and created with the same name.

Pentaho spoon uses multithreading for executing transformations.

Has anyone faced this problem? Any pointers in resolving the above error will be helpful.

Please let me know if any further information is required  regarding the error.

Thanks

**EDIT (Aug 27-10):**

To give some more information on this error:

The spoon transformation has a step which fetches 6000 rows and then each of these rows are further used in some other query which involves a join of two tables. This join query is failing with the above mentioned error - `Errcode 17`.

Comment: May be you can try editing the question by providing more info like which scripts fail/what are the major contents etc. I see that its been viewed only 8 times. Also the tag should have included pentaho/spoon IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is easy.

Goto into the `temp` folder under the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\` and simply delete the `Data#sql_29c_0.MYI`.

All done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error `Data#sql_###` appointed to the directory `c:\Windows\Temp` in my server.

I deleted the temp file and then the error disappeared.